# Leak Canary For Service

Tags: android

In my Project, I am using Foreground Service. In Few cases, app crashed and got Memory leak. Found Leak Canary Library for Detecting Memory Leaks. But for Activity and Fragment I am getting Notification and Details of Memory Leak, but for Service I am not getting any notification or Leak Details. But using Profiler found the leak in Service class but Not With Leak Canary Library. Why Leak Canary Library not giving Notification about Services in Android. Am I missing anything. As Mentioned in Document I have  added Library and Application Class. I have No idea Why it is not Working? Can You Provide a Solution?